# Is it possible to trigger a workflow outbound message when a custom related list item is added or removed?

Tags: workflow, relationships, related-list, workflowoutboundmessage

Excuse my ignorance in all of this.  I'm not well versed in Salesforce and I've been tasked with building an integration with a web app.  I've hit a brick wall on things to Google to find a solution.

In this Salesforce exists an Account object and a Product Code object.  On the Account object there is a section for Account/Product Code relationship.  I believe this is a custom related list.

Is it possible to trigger a workflow action, specifically an outbound message, whenever a Account/Product Code relationship is added or deleted?

Edit:  If it is possible to do so, what field would I be checking on or what formula would I need to get this operational?

Answer (score 3):

If Account is the parent and `Product_Code__c` is the child, then you will need a Roll-up Summary (RSF) field on Account that counts the number of Product_Code__c children.

Let's call it `Account.Product_Code_count__c`

> The RSF will only work if Product_Code__c is a detail in a master-detail relationship; if using lookup relationships - use Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries, Appexchange vendor Rollup Helper, or triggers to derive the count.

Then, you can use a workflow that executes on Account whenever `product_code_count__c` changes value (i.e. one added or deleted) to send your outbound message.

Workflows won't fire on deletion of an object, hence the use of the RSF field to act as proxy for the deletion/addition of a child

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to create workflow in Account/Product Code relationship object. If you want it to be triggered from both Account and this relationship object, you might have to create workflow in both objects.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a workflow on Account, the field will be `Product_Code__c` (Whatever your API name is), and the formula will be ISCHANGED(Product Code).

Also you will have to ensure that you have the ability to connect to whatever your endpoint url is.  What are you seeing is the outbound message status?

Comment: Having some trouble with this.  Should the field Inside the ISCHANGED supposed to be `Product_Code__c`?  I get a validation error when I try just Product Code.  However, it doesn't seem to trigger when I do `ISCHANGED( Product_Codes__c )`.

Comment: I don't know what your API name is called, What do you have set for the Evaluation criteria?  It should be "created, and every time it’s edited will suffice ".. You can click on Insert field to find the exact field you need

Comment: `ISCHANGED` can't be used with `created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria`

Comment: Sorry, created, and every time it’s edited will suffice

Comment: I checked my Product Code object and the API name is `Product_Code__c` but using `ISCHANGED( Product_Code__c  )` gives me a `Error: Field Product_Code__c does not exist. Check spelling.` error when I try to save the rule. :(

Comment: The field you should be using the one that they are using, on whatever object you expect to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. 
a WorkFlow is able to send Outbound Massage. 
you may Add new WorkFlow for the object thats has the lookup Field (Check if it was populates) or have a Workflow on the related object (Product Code) each time it has been created.
to do so:

1. Add new WorkFlow and choose on which object.
2. set your Evaluation Criteria according to your needs.
3. your rule Criteria for the Workflow should be Run this rule if the following - "Formula evaluates to true" - and use your custom lookup field with one of the formulas functions such as ISCHANGED(API Field Name)/ ISNULL(API Field Name).
4. add New Outbound Message as Immediate/Time-Dependent Workflow Actions